# reading bytearray upto specified location

Tags: java, python

Let me allow to describe my problem:
I have created socket server in python and client in java, from java I am sending multiple objects to server by using :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream append = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutput out = null;
byte finalarr[]=null;
try {
  out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
  out.writeObject(object);
  out.flush();
  byte[] objByte = bos.toByteArray();
  bos.close();
  out.close();      

  append.write(objByte.length);      
  append.write(objByte);    

  bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
  out.writeObject(value);
  out.flush();

  append.write(bos.toByteArray());
  finalarr = append.toByteArray( );

  os = sChannel.socket().getOutputStream();     
  oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
  oos.write(finalarr);
} finally {
  try {
    bos.close();
  } catch (IOException ex) {

  }
}
```

Now, `finalarr` contains byte length of `object` then actual byte[] of `object` and then byte[] of `value`. Now in python after receiving this First I want to read length of byte which is written in first position of `finalarr` then whatever length I get I want to read received array upto that length so that I will get `object` separately then the remaining part separately.

In python I have done upto this:

```
total_data=b''
    while True:            
        data = self.clientsocket.recv(1024) 
            if not data: break
            total_data += data
```

In `total_data` I am getting entire bytearray, but I don't know how I can read it so that I can get two objects separately as explained.

Comment: Is it so essential that they're read separately? Why not just splice `total_data` after the whole thing is read? `a, b = total_data[:cutover_index], total_data[cutover_index:]`

Comment: @AlexTaylor How can I decide `cutover_index`, I guess cutover_index is appended by java at first position (length of `object `), but I don't know how can I read only that length byte. I want it separately because in python i want `object` to be converted into python object using [javaobj-py3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/javaobj-py3).

Comment: For simply structured byte-level packing and unpacking, check out the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module. You can provide a format string to the `unpack` function that will read your integer, and whatever arrays you would like.